# Flash Player works on Firefox, but not on Chromium?

Tags: firefox, flash, chromium

I want to play online games, and other online stuff that requires Flash Player on the internet. Flash Player works just fine under Firefox, but in Chromium I just get a blank page. I don't know what is the exact problem or know to fix it.